# What's that rule where you aren't supposed to give visibility into an object called?

Tags: object-oriented

I forget the name of it but there's a rule that you aren't supposed to allow visibility into an objects inner makeup.  It has to do with not allowing more than one dot in the implementation like this for example:

```
return world = foo.bar.hello.world();
```

Comment: You talking about data hiding? Part of encapsulation.

Comment: "...these questions aren’t educational in any way, because there’s no way to learn about the process of discovery. A particular community member, by virtue of their experience in the field, just happens to be able to take the limited information you remembered and fill in enough of the blanks to guess the correct answer... guessing game questions do not meet our goal of making the Internet better." (http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/02/lets-play-the-guessing-game)

Comment: Law of demeter?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a name-that-thing question

Comment: @DanPichelman So where do you go for name-that-thing questions?

Comment: @RichC Perhaps [The Whiteboard](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21/the-whiteboard)?

Comment: @DanPichelman Thanks - didn't even know that existed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's part of the Law of Demeter. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter

> The Law of Demeter (LoD) or principle of least knowledge is a design guideline for developing software, particularly object-oriented programs. In its general form, the LoD is a specific case of loose coupling. The guideline was proposed at Northeastern University towards the end of 1987, and can be succinctly summarized in one of the following ways:[[1]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter#cite_note-1)
>
> - Each unit should have only limited knowledge about other units: only units "closely" related to the current unit.
> - Each unit should only talk to its friends; don't talk to strangers.
> - Only talk to your immediate friends.
>
> The fundamental notion is that a given object should assume as little as possible about the structure or properties of anything else (including its subcomponents), in accordance with the principle of "[information hiding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_hiding)"...

Comment: Thanks @gnat. I wish the SO editing made this kind of formatting a bit easier, but I was kind of pressed for time.